# in-memory string in I/O

Tags: c++, io

I was reading about CPP I/O (from *C++ Primer*) and I came across a statement:

> We'd like to use >> to read data regardless of whether we're reading a console window, a disk file, or an in-memory string.

What is **in-memory** string?

Comment: Where did you find the statement?

Comment: I think "in-memory string" refers simply to a string which is for example declared like `std::string str;`.

Comment: I guess it means ````std::stringstream````?

Comment: Please provide a reference